# CS0165 y no veo el fallo c# Visual studio 2019

Tags: c#

me da el error CS0165 o lo que es lo mismo: Uso de la variable local no asignada.

Dejo el código aquí a ver si alguien consigue saber que ocurre en el codigo para que me de ese error, llevo horas intentando ver que ocurre y no encuentro NADA acerca de ello, asi que recurro al comite de expertos picateclas. Acabo de empezar no hace mucho con c# y voy poco a poco, esto es un conversor de decimal a binario y viceversa.

```
        {
            case "a":
                long binario = decimalBinario(numero);
                Console.WriteLine("El numero decimal " + numero + " en binario es " + binario);
                break;
            case "b":
                int decimalB = binarioDecimal(binario); //el error está aquí en (binario)
                Console.WriteLine("El numero binario" + binario, "en decimal es: " + decimalB);
                break;
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería. Un saludo!

Comment: ahi te falta codigo pon el switch completo

Comment: switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "a":
                    long binario = decimalBinario(numero);
                    Console.WriteLine("El numero decimal " + numero + " en binario es " + binario);
                    break;
                case "b":
                    int decimalB = binarioDecimal(binario);
                    Console.WriteLine("El numero binario" + binario, "en decimal es: " + decimalB);
                    break;
            }
        }

Answer (score 2):

Cada seccion del case es un intervalo por si mismo.

Con lo cual, cuando definiste la variable

```
long binario = decimalBinario(numero);
```

Solo vale dentro del case 1. No vale en el otro case.

Es mas, si entro por el case 1, no va a entrar por el 2, entonces cuando estes en el 2, que valor esperas que tenga?

Si queres usarlo en mas de un lugar dentro del switch, deberias definirla afuera.

Para mas info, mira estos [ejercicios oficiales](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/)